# 3-way bind date format with AngularJS and Firebase

Tags: angularjs, firebase, bind, datapicker

In all my projects I'm running into the same problem trying to figure out what the best way is to have a proper way of binding a timestamp (date) with my view and Firebase. I'm currently using the `md-datepicker` directive from Angular-Material but unfortunately this directive only supports a date object, and because Firebase won't accept a date object the value will always be empty.

In several projects I'm storing epoch timestamps in milliseconds in Firebase. Is there any possibility to have a proper 3-way data binding with epoch timestamps in Firebase and the `md-datepicker`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it by creating my own bind function and converting to an ISO date string when saving it and converting it into a date object when fetching it.

It user $parse to evaluate expressions in the given scope and to update the local variable in that scope. Here is the service:

```
angular.module('symApp').service('realtimeService', function($rootScope, $q, $log, $window, $state,
                                                           $firebaseObject, $parse) {

// Utilities
var regexIso8601 = /^([\+-]?\d{4}(?!\d{2}\b))((-?)((0[1-9]|1[0-2])(\3([12]\d|0[1-9]|3[01]))?|W([0-4]\d|5[0-2])(-?[1-7])?|(00[1-9]|0[1-9]\d|[12]\d{2}|3([0-5]\d|6[1-6])))([T\s]((([01]\d|2[0-3])((:?)[0-5]\d)?|24\:?00)([\.,]\d+(?!:))?)?(\17[0-5]\d([\.,]\d+)?)?([zZ]|([\+-])([01]\d|2[0-3]):?([0-5]\d)?)?)?)?$/;
var convertDateStringsToDates = function (input) {
    // Ignore things that aren't objects.
    if (typeof input !== "object") return input;
    for (var key in input) {
        if (!input.hasOwnProperty(key)) continue;
        var value = input[key];
        var match;
        // Check for string properties which look like dates.
        if (typeof value === "string" && (match = value.match(regexIso8601))) {
            var milliseconds = Date.parse(match[0]);
            if (!isNaN(milliseconds)) {
                input[key] = new Date(milliseconds);
            }
        } else if (typeof value === "object") {
            // Recurse into object
            convertDateStringsToDates(value);
        }
    }
};

this.bindVar = function(scope, remote_path, local_var_name) {
// This function binds a local variable in scope to a remote variable in firebase
// and handles any dates by converting them into iso formatted strings.
// Note: Arrays inside the object are not supported

// Parse the local variable name so we can interact with the scope variable
var parsed = $parse(local_var_name);

// Grab the reference to the realtime database
var ref = firebase.database().ref().child(remote_path);

// Create the firebase object and set watchers to bind the data
var remote = $firebaseObject(ref);
remote.$loaded().then(function() {

    // Watch for changes and call $save on firebaseObject
    // Have to do this when loaded otherwise we'll get a change from nothing to null and write null to realtime database...

    // Local watcher
    scope.$watch(local_var_name,
        function(value) {
            // This is called when the local variable changes
            $log.debug(local_var_name, 'local value changed');

            // Convert to JSON to change dates to strings
            var local = angular.fromJson(angular.toJson(parsed(scope)));

            // Check if local has changed with respect to remote (stops us from saving when we don't need to)
            if(!angular.equals(remote.value, local)){
                remote.value = local;
                remote.$save();
                $log.debug(local_var_name, 'saved to remote with value: ', remote.value);
            }
        },
        true
    );

    // Remote watcher
    scope.$watch(
        function () {
            return remote.value;
        },
        function(value) {
            // If the firebase value has changed, then update the local value
            $log.debug(local_var_name, 'remote value changed');

            // Convert date strings from firebase into date objects before setting scope variable
            var remote_with_date_objects = $.extend(true,{},remote.value);
            convertDateStringsToDates(remote_with_date_objects);

            if(!angular.equals(remote_with_date_objects,parsed(scope))){
                parsed.assign(scope, remote_with_date_objects);
                $log.debug(local_var_name, 'updated with remote value: ', remote_with_date_objects);
            }
        },
        true
    );

    });
};
```

});

And here is how you use it in your controller to bind a scope variable:

```
realtimeService.bindVar($scope, 'datum/charter', 'charter');
```

My $scope.charter object has its own objects and arrays within it and everything seems to sync correctly. When saving data it uses **angular.toJson** and **angular.fromJson** to convert all the date objects to strings. When loading remote data it uses a custom function **convertDateStringsToDates()** to convert any date strings within the object to date objects whenever the remote is updated.